# C++ Read inFile separated by a comma and a space

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, arraylist, readfile

i am required to read a file with data of this format (Date, ID, Activity, Qty, Price) in the main test class. I'm supposed to read and store the "Date" values into int day,month,year of type Date, followed by "ID, Activity, Qty, Price" of stock class.

```
02/08/2011, ABC, BUY, 100, 20.00 
05/08/2011, ABC, BUY, 20, 24.00
06/08/2011, ABC, BUY, 200, 36.00
```

i stored the values accordingly to Stock() constructor and store all data via push_back() in my own "Vector" class. what must i add/ edit so that i can retrieve the rows of data in Vector and get(Date, ID, Activity, Qty, Price) and make calculations for qty and price.

```
#include"Vector.h"
#include"Date.h"
#include"Stock.h"
#include<iomanip>
#include<fstream>
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main(){

    string stockcode;
    string act;
    int qty;
    double p;
    int d,m,y;
    char x;

    //declare file stream variables
    ifstream inFile;
    ofstream outFile;

    //open the file
    inFile.open("share-data.txt");

    //code for data manipulation
    cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);

    while(!inFile.eof()){
    inFile>> d >> x >> m >> x >> y >> x
    >> stockcode >> act >> qty >> x >> p;

    Stock s1(d,m,y,stockcode,act,qty,p);

    stockcode = stockcode.substr(0, stockcode.length()-1);
act = act.substr(0, act.length()-1);

Stock s1(d,m,y,stockcode,act,qty,p);
stockList.push_back(s1);

    }

    inFile.close();

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

i have my own Vector class which is needed for this assignment because i am not allowed to use #include default vector

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

template <class T>
class Vector
{

public:

    Vector();               // default constructor
    virtual ~Vector() {};   //destructor
    bool isEmpty() const;
    bool isFull() const;
    void print() const;
    void push_back(T);
    T pop_back();
    T at(int i); 
    int Size();
    //Vector<T> operator +=(T);

private:
    int size;
    T list[100];
};

template <class T>
Vector<T>::Vector()
{
    size = 0;
}

template <class T>
Vector<T> Vector<T>::operator +=(T i)
{
    this->push_back(i);
    return *this;
}

template <class T>
bool Vector<T>::isEmpty() const
{
    return (size == 0);
}

template <class T>
bool Vector<T>::isFull() const
{
    return (size == 100);
}

template <class T>
void Vector<T>::push_back(T x)
{
    list[size] = x;
    size++;
}

template <class T>
T Vector<T>::operator[](T i)
{
    return list[i];
}

template <class T>
T Vector<T>::at(int i)
{
    if(i<size)
        return list[i];
    throw 10;
}

template <class T>
T Vector<T>::pop_back()
{
    T y;
    size--;
    y= list[size];
    return y;
}

template <class T>
void Vector<T>::print() const
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        cout << list[i] << " ";
    cout << endl;
}

template <class T>
int Vector<T>::Size() 
{
    return size;
}
```

and here's my Stock class

```
 #include"Date.h"

   Stock::Stock()
{
    stockID="";
    act="";
    qty=0;
    price=0.0;
}

Stock::Stock(int d, int m , int y, string id,string a, int q, double p)
:date(d,m,y){
    stockID = id;
    act = a;
    qty = q;
    price = p;

}
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `string::substr`

```
act = act.substr(0, act.length()-1);
```

You can do the same for the other string variables.